# Does anything already exist to flatten a mix of single instances and arrays of instances?

Tags: c#

I just wrote myself a utility function

```
    private static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>(params object[] items) where T : class
    {
        return items.SelectMany(c => c is T ? new[] {c as T} : (IEnumerable<T>) c);
    }
```

It allowed me to go from this:

```
        var lines = records
            .GroupBy(c => new {c.CODEID, c.DESCRIPTION})
            .SelectMany(c => 
                new[] { string.Format(insertRecord, c.Key.CODEID, c.Key.DESCRIPTION) }
                .Concat(c.Select(d => string.Format(insertDetail, d.CODEID, d.CODESEQ, d.DATAVALUE, d.DISPLAYVALUE)))
                .Concat(new [] {Environment.NewLine}))
            ;
```

To this:

```
        var lines2 = records
            .GroupBy(c => new {c.CODEID, c.DESCRIPTION})
            .SelectMany(c => Flatten<string>(
                string.Format(insertRecord, c.Key.CODEID, c.Key.DESCRIPTION),
                c.Select(d => string.Format(insertDetail, d.CODEID, d.CODESEQ, d.DATAVALUE, d.DISPLAYVALUE)),
                Environment.NewLine))
            ;
```

Before I commit such an obscure looking thing to my code base, I wanted to see if I was overlooking some other obvious way to avoid the use of `Concat` in the first way above...

NOTE: maybe this belongs on code review... not sure

Comment: Maybe there's a good reason to make all the output an enumerable sequence like this instead of the standard `foreach (var g in groups)` and such, but it's definitely not a given. I would strongly consider rewriting with `foreach` and hiding the code inside an iterator block.

Comment: I don't know if it's a good reason, but for functional tasks like generating database scripts from a csv file, I've been growing more and more fond of functional style C#.  I don't want to go nuts trying to make the language bend over this, but it's interesting to see what I can and can't do.  After all, I want to have a job in 5 years when all the interesting .NET positions start calling for F# :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the code simpler, but more importantly make the whole thing statically typed, by creating a method that simply prepends a single item to the start of a sequence:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Prepend<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> sequence,
    T item)
{
    yield return item;
    foreach(var current in sequence)
        yield return current;
}
```

And one to append an item to the end of a sequence:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Append<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> sequence,
    T item)
{
    foreach(var current in sequence)
        yield return current;
    yield return item;
}
```

Now your method can be written as:

```
var lines = records
    .GroupBy(c => new {c.CODEID, c.DESCRIPTION})
    .SelectMany(c => 
        c.Select(d => 
            string.Format(insertDetail, d.CODEID, d.CODESEQ, d.DATAVALUE, d.DISPLAYVALUE))
        .Prepend(string.Format(insertRecord, c.Key.CODEID, c.Key.DESCRIPaTION))
        .Append(Environment.NewLine);
```

---

The other route you can go is to write an `AsSequence` method that can more effectively turn an item into a sequence of size one.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> AsSequence<T>(this T item)
{
    yield return item;
}
```

This does clean up your original code a bit by making the entire query one fluent sequence of method calls:

```
var lines = records
    .GroupBy(c => new {c.CODEID, c.DESCRIPTION})
    .SelectMany(c => 
        string.Format(insertRecord, c.Key.CODEID, c.Key.DESCRIPTION)
        .AsSequence()
        .Concat(c.Select(d => 
            string.Format(insertDetail, d.CODEID, d.CODESEQ, d.DATAVALUE, d.DISPLAYVALUE)))
        .Concat(Environment.NewLine.AsSequence()));
```